# How to send messages over internet socket

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

My server (listening) is as:

```
import os
from socket import *
host = ""
port = 1337
buf = 1024
addr = (host, port)
UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
UDPSock.bind(addr)
print("Waiting to receive messages...")
while True:
    (data, addr) = UDPSock.recvfrom(buf)
    data=data.decode('ascii')
    print("Received message: " + data)
    if data == "exit":
        break
UDPSock.close()
os._exit(0)
```

and my client is

```
import os
from socket import *
host = "MY INTERNET IP"
port = 1337
addr = (host, port)
UDPSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
while True:
    data = input("Enter message to send or type 'exit': ")
    data=data.encode('ascii')
    UDPSock.sendto(data, addr)
    if data == "exit":
        break
UDPSock.close()
os._exit(0)
```

so I need to know, how do I transmit these messages over internet? i have all my ports open on my network yet i can not receive any messages while trying to do that. My server is listening on port 1337 and my client is transmitting to MY INTERNET IP where a server is listening on the port it is transmitting on. so how do I get this to work, what do i do wrong? thing is, it works while doing lan. it's cozy, but very pointless since i would like to transmit text over web

**EDIT**

Got my friend to run client side. Python just returned 4.
Nothing happened on my side.

Comment: So your code works? Then this is a networking problem. You need to open ports on your router and give your server a static ip and know your external IP address...

Comment: I have DMZ'd my computer, set a static ip, and opened the ports.

Comment: Seeing this question has many views and a disappointing amount of solution, 5 years later OP checking back in here. Assuming everything else is done right, I would try changing the bound host from `""` to `"0.0.0.0"` as the latter causes the program to listen on all network interfaces.